# ConMan start error, cannot recognize options in conman.conf, how to fix?

Tags: console

conman version:
    conman.x86_64                         0.2.5-2.4.el6                @rhel-install

conman.conf

```
server syslog="local4"

global ipmiopts="admin,Password@_"

global log="/home/tops/%N.log"

global logopts="nosanitize,timestamp"



console name="17B001682" dev="ipmi:10.153.107.105"
```

running output:

```
[tops@HP380 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/conman restart

Starting ConMan: ERROR:     CONFIG[/home/tops/conman.conf:2]: unrecognized token 'ipmiopts'

ERROR:     CONFIG[/home/tops/conman.conf:6]: console [17B001682] device "ipmi:10.153.107.105" type unrecognized

ERROR:     Configuration "/home/tops/conman.conf" has no consoles defined

                                                       [FAILED]
```

Why this error takes place and how can I fix it? thanks!

Comment: Please explain the question so that people might be able to help

Comment: I want to know what caused the error and how I can make it work. 3x!